# Interrupt handling in Device Driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, interrupt

I have written a simple character driver and requested IRQ on a gpio pin and wrtten a handler for it.

```
err = request_irq(irq, irq_handler,IRQF_SHARED | IRQF_TRIGGER_RISING,  INTERRUPT_DEVICE_NAME,  raspi_gpio_devp);

static irqreturn_t irq_handler(int irq, void *arg);
```

now from theory i know that Upon interrupt the interrupt Controller with tell the processor to call `do_IRQ()` which will check the IDT and call my interrupt handler for this line.

how does the kernel know that the interrupt handler was for this particular device file

Also I know that Interrupt handlers do not run in any process context. But let say I am accessing any variable declared out side scope of handler, a static global flag = 0, In the handler I make flag = 1 indicating that an interrupt has occurred. That variable is in process context. So I am confused how this handler not in any process context modify a variable in process context.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*The kernel does not know that this particular interrupt is for a particular device.*

The only thing it knows is that it must call `irq_handler` with `raspi_gpio_devp` as a parameter. (like this: `irq_handler(irq, raspi_gpio_devp)`).

If your irq line is shared, you should check if your device generated an IRQ or not. Code:

```
int irq_handler(int irq, void* dev_id) {
    struct raspi_gpio_dev *raspi_gpio_devp = (struct raspi_gpio_dev *) dev_id;
    if (!my_gpio_irq_occured(raspi_gpio_devp))
        return IRQ_NONE;
    /* do stuff here */
    return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

The interrupt handler runs in interrupt context. *But you can access static variables declared outside the scope of the interrupt*.

Usually, what an interrupt handler does is:

- check interrupt status
- retrieve information from the hardware and store it somewhere (a buffer/fifo for example)
- `wake_up()` a kernel process waiting for that information

If you want to be really confident with the do and don't of interrupt handling, the best thing to read about is what a process is for the kernel.

An excellent book dealing with this is [Linux Kernel Developpement by Robert Love.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468)

Answer (score 7):

The kernel doesn't know which device the interrupt pertains to. It is possible for a single interrupt to be shared among multiple devices. Previously this was quite common. It is becoming less so due to improved interrupt support in interrupt controllers and introduction of message-signaled interrupts. Your driver must determine whether the interrupt was from your device (i.e. whether your device needs "service").

You can provide context to your interrupt handler via the "void *arg" provided. This should never be process-specific context, because a process might exit leaving pointers dangling (i.e. referencing memory which has been freed and/or possibly reallocated for other purposes).

A global variable is not "in process context". It is in every context -- or no context if you prefer. When you hear "not in process context", that means a few things: (1) you cannot block/sleep (because what process would you be putting to sleep?), (2) you cannot make any references to user-space virtual addresses (because what would those references be pointing to?), (3) you cannot make references to "current task" (since there isn't one or it's unknown).

Typically, a driver's interrupt handler pushes or pulls data into "driver global" data areas from which/to which the process context end of the driver can transfer data.

Comment: How do I code to determine that interrupt is for my device...Comparing the irq argument with a known IRQ value ? So this global variable that I am talking of say for eg: A int flag to indicate interrupt has occurred should be in side a per device structure that should be passed to the handler as void  *arg ???

Comment: Typically you would ask your device. If your device can't tell you whether it generated the interrupt, then you'll need to make sure the interrupt line is *not* shared (leave off IRQF_SHARED).

Comment: The "void *arg" is available for whatever you want to use it for. Typically, it points to some sort of device-specific data structure (because often it's possible to have more than one instance of a device). You can also just keep global data in a global/static variable.

Answer (score 1):

This is to reply your question :-

> how does the kernel know that the interrupt handler was for this particular >device file?

1. Each System-On-Chip documents will mention interrupt numbers for different devices connected to different interrupt lines.
2. The Same Interrupt number has to be mentioned in the Device Tree entry for instantiation of device driver.
3. The Device driver's usual probe function parses the Device tree data structure and reads the IRQ number and registers the handler using the register_irq function.
4. If there are multiple devices to a single IRQ number/line, then the IRQ status register(for different devices if mapped under the same VM space) can be used inside the IRQ handler to differentiate.

Please read more in my [blog](http://rackbrains-esoft.blogspot.in/2016/01/how-does-linux-kernel-handle-shared.html)